# Is it possible to send a POST variable through webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have to automatate registration form on production, where it has active CAPTCHA. I run my script on test server using a preset CAPTCHA. To handle captcha on production the developer has asked me to pass a POST variable, using which he will bypass CAPTCHA for my script.

Is it possible to pass a random POST variable along with form submit in webdriver? If not, is there any other secure way to handle CAPTCHA only for my script?

Comment: I don't believe it's directly possible to pass a POST variable via selenium, you could probably pull off some selenium-javascript POST sorcery with selenium's `runScript` and `getEval`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something came in my mind I am just sharing that with you might not be possible but you can give it a try

1. Write a javascript which add a input element in the form
2. Use JavascriptExector to execute the script, logically that scriot should add the element in the form. // THIS IS THE PART I AM NOT SURE IF POSSIBLE :)
3. Now press submit using selenium

Comment: You could use a Selenium JavascriptExecutor to do this.  Yes, it will work.

Comment: Thanks a lot A Paul and djangofan. Your method worked. I was able to add element, on recieving which developer bypassed the captcha at back end. However the front end JS check could not be overcome through this method. Now I am looking do it by setting cookie. Let us see how it turns out. Anyway thanks a ton :)

Comment: Welcome @Husam. If this helped you please dont forget to mark the answer as correct. It will help others. :)